# msbuild - static lib compilation failed after adding resource file to project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I have a C++ library which is compiled as dynamic and static library. Recently I add resource version file to source. The dynamic library compilation works fine, but **static library** compilation started failing for **64 bit target** with following error:

```
LINK : warning LNK4068: /MACHINE not specified; defaulting to X86

 x64\Release\dllmain.obj : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'
```

Following is my compilation script:

```
@ECHO OFF
call "%VS140COMNTOOLS%"\\vsvars32.bat
SET SourceDir=D:\Projects\MySampleLib
SET TargetDir=D:\Projects\Packages

ECHO 32 bit MySampleLib .LIB compilation VS2010

msbuild.exe %SourceDir%\MySampleLib\MySampleLib.vcxproj /t:Clean;Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release;Platform=Win32;ConfigurationType=StaticLibrary;PlatformToolset=v100


ECHO 64 bit MySampleLib .LIB compilation VS2010

msbuild.exe %SourceDir%\MySampleLib\MySampleLib.vcxproj /t:Clean;Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64;ConfigurationType=StaticLibrary;PlatformToolset=Windows7.1SDK
```

The error occurs when **Lib.exe** command tries to link the **MySampleLib.res**

**Note:** The error only appeared after I added the resource file. I **don't want** to add the resource file to static libs.

Comment: You can't add resources to a static library.  Also as static libs don't get linked (linking happens when the final executable is built), whatever you have done to invoke the linker for a static library is the start of your problems.  The __Lib.exe__ command is the library manager not the linker.

Comment: @RichardCritten I don't want to add the resource file to the static libs. I only added them for the dynamic version. In my compilation script i haven't done anything either.

Comment: Are you sure this has anything to do with the resource at all? The error seems to be clear enough: you're compiling 64bit object files (hence the *module machine type 'x64'* mention) but don't pass /MACHINE:x64 to the linker (hence the */MACHINE not specified; defaulting to X86*) so it tries to link 32bit object files. Which doesn't work since it's given 64bit object files.

Answer (score 2):

I finally fixed the issue by modifying the following `.vcxproj` entry

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ResourceCompile Include="MySampleLib.rc" />
</ItemGroup>
```

to

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(ConfigurationType)'!='StaticLibrary'">
    <ResourceCompile Include="MySampleLib.rc" />
</ItemGroup>
```

This prevented linking of resource file in static compilation.

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of the error by specifying the /MACHINE type when building the libs in the terminal as per the guide.

```
 lib /def:libfftw3-3.def /MACHINE:x64
```